# TinyMCE format for multiple elements/selectors

Tags: formatting, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add a custom format to TinyMCE, that will add a custom class to any heading element selected, or even any element selected at all.

Declaring format for only a single element/tag **works fine**. In the following example, if your selection is within the `H1`, this format will add a class to it.
However, if your selection is within the `H3` element, the element will be converted to `H1` alongside receiving a custom class.

```
array(
 'title' => 'Custom Style',
 'inline' => '',
 'block' => 'h1',
 'selector' => '',
 'classes' => 'custom-class'
)
```

I tried using `,` and `|` separated lists of elements, or even completely empty but everything throws an error:

```
'block' => 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6'
  // or
'selector' => 'h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6'
  // or
'block' => ''
'selector' => ''
```

---

Is it possible to support multiple block elements, or simply add the class to the selected element - no matter what it is?

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not sure how to make a custom format apply to *any element*, if you want to apply to **headings only**, you would write it out like this:

```
array(
    'title' => 'Custom Style',
    'selector' => 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', // the selectors we want the class to apply to
    'classes' => 'custom-class'
)
```

So the user would need to create any of those heading elements first. Then they can select it and apply the 'custom-class' to it.

Referenced from here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/format-custom/

Answer (score 2):

Using the universal selector will choose any element.

```
'selector' => '*'
```

Doing it this way will always use the inner-most element. It doesn't differentiate between elements that are block or inline. If you want to do that, you'll have to provide a list, as in Moondrop's answer.